# Oracle UPDATE remove prefixed value from column data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that prefixes a p_id with a p_number

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
   SET t1.p_id = CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(t2.p_number,' ') 
                           FROM tble2 t2 
                          WHERE t2.id = t1.p_id)
                        , t1.p_id) 
 WHERE t1.p_id = '19680';
```

Which basically takes values like

```
t2.p_number:X12
t1.p_id:    19680
```

and turns it into

```
t2.p_number:X12
t1.p_id:    X12 19680
```

What I have been asked for is a 'rollback' script, baring in mind the only column I will know the value of is the '19680'! 
I have looked at the REPLACE command but not sure if I can get it to work; any ideas?

---

Resolved!

Thanks guys, a log of good tips there, I have gone for what in the end looks a quite simple query from Ben.

There's quite a bit of history behind this issue, where basically a client has entered the values for p_id and has entered duplicates. They therefore want to prefix the p_number onto the p_id to make them unique again (once entered the client can not update), but they also want a get-out-clause, in case something goes wrong so they want to be able to remove the prefixed data.

The p_id is actually used within the system so virtual tables and code changes were not really feasible in this scenario, rather it was easiest to just update the client's data for them.

Cheers guys, hope the client is happy with the proposal.

Comment: This massively depends on what values are valid in each column. You're quoting `p_id`, which implies that it's a character field not a number. If this is the case, and any values are valid, this is completely impossible. If it's a number then it's fairly easy...

Comment: @Ben I guess looking at the OP query p_id could be alpha-numeric though it's badly named.

Comment: Can't you rollback by retrieving the number after space and updating the column? What's the problem in it?

Comment: @Indoknight; if `p_id` is a character then space is a valid character, i.e. the update value could be `R56 T4543   fdgdfg`. The OP will have to clarify what is going on.

Comment: Hi guys, yes both id and number are varchar (and badly named)

Comment: @Indoknight yes that's what I'm looking to do, trim away everything from the prefixed string (so 'X12 ') in the example's case to put the value back to 19680.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my 2c.

**Do not** update your original field. If there's a possibility that you want to roll it back then you cause yourself massive problems. Create a new field that you update with the new values. When you want to reference this field you can do so. When you want to reference another field you can do that.

More generally, this is a good tactic for any fields that you want to "fix". You may improve what you're "fixing" later on and if you've overwritten the original data you're unable to. Always keep the raw data and then you can re-use it as often as you like.

If all you want to do is remove everything before the first space then the following will work:

```
update the_table
   set p_id = substr(p_id, instr(p_id, ' ') + 1);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa4ae/3)

Comment: It's better to search for LAST space, not the first as in your case.

Comment: Only if that's what the OP wants @EgorSkriptunoff; yes possibly.

Comment: @Ben - Jeez so simple in the end! I have gone for you fix, cheers.

Comment: As I say @KPS-UK, I recommend against it and Branko makes a very good point in his comments and answer. You can generate this as a virtual column in your second table... there's no need to update the first at all.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, do not store the data you can **infer**.

Just prefix the field in the client code, or in a VIEW, or a virtual column (Oracle 11), without modifying the original value. Since you haven't modified it, there is nothing to rollback.

Comment: Great point! I should have mentioned that in my answer suggesting the use of a virtual column for this.

Comment: You can't use a virtual column and a view may be slow as the data is stored in a second table...

Comment: @Ben A JOIN _may_ be slow, but I wouldn't make that assumption and compromise data integrity for caching, before performing appropriate measurements on realistic amounts of data...

Comment: @Ben As for the virtual column - it can exist in the original table _before_ JOIN-ing it to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to do this simply, then trim away the prefix till the space and get back your original value. If you are looking at a better option, then I'd say to create another column like "old_p_id" and then push the old one into it. If you want to rollback, you can always update p_id with old_p_id.

```
+----------------------+
¦ p_id      ¦ old_p_id ¦
¦-----------+----------¦
¦ X12 19680 ¦  19680   ¦
¦ X13 19681 ¦  19681   ¦
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Oracle are you using? If Oracle 11g you could use virtual columns for this!

```
alter table table1
add new_column as p_number || ' ' || p_id;
```

I'm assuming here that all of your columns are of type varchar.

With this approach you will have to update client code to reference the new column.

Comment: The number is stored in a different table, you still have to store the data from the second table.

Comment: I read over that bit. In that case a VIEW is my recommended approach.